# Ruby `add_item': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

New to Ruby. Receiving error:

> item_container.rb:14:in `add_item': undefined method`<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I know what this error means but can't understand what caused it and how to fix it? Everything was okay before making `ClassMethods`, `InstanceMethods`, and adding callback.

```
#item_container.rb
module ItemContainer

    module ClassMethods

        def min_price
            100 
        end

    end

    module InstanceMethods

        def add_item(item)
            unless item.price < self.class.min_price #<----- error line
                @items.push item
            end
        end

    end

    def self.included(base)
        base.extend ClassMethods
        base.class_eval do 
            include InstanceMethods
        end
    end

end
```

```
#init.rb
require_relative "item_container"
require_relative "cart"
require_relative "order"
require_relative "item"
require_relative "virtual_item"
require_relative "real_item"

item1 = VirtualItem.new({ :price => 10, :name => "car" })
item2 = RealItem.new({ :price => 100, :weight => 20, :name => "kettle" })
item3 = RealItem.new({ :price=> 10, :weight => 100, :name => "dishwasher" })

cart = Cart.new
cart.add_item item1
cart.add_item item2
```

```
class Item

    @@discount = 0.05

    def self.discount
        if Time.now.month == 2
            @@discount + 0.1
        else
            @@discount 
        end
    end

    def initialize(options={})
        @real_price     = options[:price]
        @name               = options[:name]
    end

    attr_accessor :real_price
    attr_reader   :name

    def info    
        yield(price)
        yield(name)
    end

    def price
        (@real_price - @real_price * self.class.discount) + tax if @realprice
    end

    private

        def tax
            type_tax = if self.class == VirtualItem
                1
            else
                2
            end
            cost_tax = if @real_price > 5 
                @real_price * 0.2
            else
                @real_price * 0.1
            end
            cost_tax + type_tax
        end

end
```

Comment: What do `item1.price` and `item2.price` return before `cart = Cart.new` line? I would look for the cause of this error in `VirtualItem` or `RealItem` class, depending on the answer to my first question.

Comment: The error says that `item.price` is `nil`, and there is no method `<` for `nil`. But I can't tell you why that's happened, because you haven't provided a [mcve]. My **guess** is that in the initialize method for either `VirtualItem` or `RealItem`, you are never setting `@price` - and therefore it remains `nil`.

Comment: Price of an item with discount and tax

Comment: No, specifically, what's the result of `item1.price` and `item2.price`? One of them is probably `nil`, which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
def price
  (@real_price - @real_price * self.class.discount) + tax if @realprice
end
```

You have a typo here, it should be `if @real_price`.

Comment: Note that if the typo is fixed `price` will still return `nil` if no `@real_price` is set.